# Changing a made style in html

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm trying to create a navigation menu for users:

#### HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
.nav-pills > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KJFj5/

When I click on each navigation tab it doesn't paint it with blue. My question is if there is a way to modify it so it will. Thank you!

Comment: How is this in anyway [tag:asp-classic]?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achive here. To change the style on your navigation tab when clicking them I would write you css like so:

```
.nav-pills > li {
    float: left;
}

.nav-pills > li > a {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-pills > li {
    margin-left: 2px;
    list-style:none;
}

.nav-pills > li > a:active { /*Use the :active pseudo selector*/
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change CSS class for active menu item - `active`. Now "Home" is active.

Comment: I didnt understand - how do i change it on a click

Comment: You should use JavaScript.

Comment: No need for javascript here, CSS3 will do what you need.